# Recursive Async Looping in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, promise

I'm trying to do a recursive async loop to trace all the children of a particular object from a third-party lib in nodejs.

Heres the pseudo code:

```
var tracer = function(nodes){
  var promises [];

  nodes.forEach(function(node){

    // trace returns a promise ...
    var promise = builder.trace(node)
    promises.push(promise);

    promise.then(function(tree){

      // if we had children, get those
      if(tree.children.length){
        promises.push.apply(promises, tracer(tree.children));
      }
    });   

  });

  return promises;
};

RSVP.all(tracer(myArr)).then(function(allTrees){ ... });
```

but I can't put my finger on how to get them all to resolve correctly and returns the results in one array.

Comment: How does `tracer(myArr)` even have `.then`? In this code, you're not returning a promise to use `.then` on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must not `push` the recursive promises on the array in the delayed callback. Instead, you'll need to push a promise that represents the recursive results (resolves with those delayed produced promises) right away. Luckily, you even get exactly that back from that `then` call.

Additionally, I would swap out the `each` for a `map`, and do `RSVP.all` immediately inside the function, for not expecting the caller to deal with that.

```
function tracer(nodes){
  var promises = nodes.map(function(node){
    // trace returns a promise ...
    var promise = builder.trace(node)
    var recusivePromise = promise.then(function(tree){
      // if we had children, get those
      if (tree.children.length)
        return tracer(tree.children));
      else
        return node;// the leaf node itself
    });
    return recusivePromise; // which will resolve with the `tracer(…)` result
                            // or the leaf
  });
  return RSVP.all(promises);
}

tracer(myArr).then(function(allTrees){ … });
```

Comment: Note: This return a lists of lists vs a flat array.

Comment: @amcdnl: Yes, it's supposed to match the tree structure. If you want a flat array, make each `recursivePromise` resolve with an array (by returning leafs in singleton arrays), and add a `concat` step after `.all()`.

Comment: @DanKanze: It's basic functional programming :-)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with a counter type approach ...

```
var traceDeps = function(parents, cb){
  var count = 0, 
    trees = [], 
    trace = function(nodes){
      nodes.forEach(function(node){
        count++;
        builder.trace(node).then(function(tree){
          trees.push(tree);

          if(tree.children.length){
            trace(tree.children);
          }

          count--;
          if (count === 0) cb(trees);
        });
      });
    };

  trace(parents);
};

traceDeps(myArr, function(trees){ ... });
```

Comment: Why so complicated? No need to use callbacks and counters when you can use promises. Also you are ignoring errors with this approach.

Comment: If any of the `trace()` promises is getting rejected, you won't notice (and instead wait indefinitely for your callback that is never called)

Comment: This solution is inferior to Bergi's and ignores errors. You should consider using his instead.

Comment: Ya, I agree.  Thanks for the post @Bergi